# Build and use local package for AWS Lambda using serverless framework

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, package, serverless-framework

I am trying to package a local python package¹ and use it within an AWS lambda deployed via the Serverless framework. I already use [serverless-python-requirements](https://github.com/UnitedIncome/serverless-python-requirements) plugin to add pip dependencies to deployed package.

How can I proceed ?

Shall I create a package and zip it? Or generate a whl file and use pip? And then, how to deploy it?

---

¹: I cannot just add it to "normal codebase" as I want to share it with other bricks (Glue jobs for example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Here's the solution:

###### 1.

Build a `.whl` file corresponding to package using

```sh
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

within a parent directory.

###### 2.

Add the relative path to this `.whl` file to used pip requirement file (`requirements.txt` for instance) :

```
req0==1.0.9
req1==5.5.0
../<relative path to local package>/dist/<package name>-<version>-<details>.whl # generated .whl file's name
```

###### 3.

`serverless-python-requirements` will automagically pack this dependency within the deployed archive when doing `sls deploy`. How cool is that, huh!